# How do I fix the following many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to build a database as follows:

We have one table, called Organization. An Organization can have one or more products, which they sell. Then, I have a table called Products, which lists the Product title, cost, and amount sold.

How can I create a relationship where a organization.product can contain a reference to multiple rows from the products table?

I would imagine I would need to potentially create another table?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  You would create another table to represent the many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yes, an `OrganizationProduct` table.

Comment: If the OrganizationProduct table contained multiple products, wouldn't this be an array of products, which would violate normalization rules?

Comment: Do Organizations share products? If not, then Organization -> Product is a one-to-many relationship. Otherwise it is a many-to-many and @GordonLinoff is correct.

Comment: Yes, some Organizations can share the same product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this for your Organization and Product tables.

```
Organization
    Id (Primary Key)
    Name
    ....

Product
    Id (Primary Key)
    Name
    Cost
    ....
```

Then you would create a join table like this that would link your Organization to Products.

```
OrganizationProduct 
    Id (Primary Key)
    OrganizationId (Foreign Key to Organization Table)
    ProductId (Foreign Key to Product Table)
```

Comment: The join will solve the issue in OPs question. RDBMS is relational and will show one-to-many or many-to-many without issue. A new table should not be created. Using a view or materialized view will be a good way to "save" the one-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is have a table representing your products and in that table one of the fields should represent the Organisation which has the product, called something like org_id.

Then in your Organisation table you will have an id column to join with org_id from the product table.

Eg:

```
 Products:
 id     int
 org_id int
 name   varchar
 colour varchar
 .....
 any other information about products


 Organisations:
 id    int
 name  varchar
 type varchar
 ...
 other organisation details
```

Now when you want to list all the products for each company you do:

```
    SELECT products.name, organisations.name 
    FROM products 
    JOIN organisations 
    ON products.org_id = organisations.id;
```

New information, products can belong ot multiple organisations. Now you need a table called organisationProducts to act as an intermediary between the two tables and create a many to many relationship:

```
   Products:
   id int
   name varchar

   Organisations:
   id int
   name varchar

   OrgnisationProducts:
   id int
   Org_id
   Prod_id
```

You join prod_id to products.id and org_id to organisations.id

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called an associative table. Let's call it OrgProduct (I name all my tables in the singular; some shops name them plural, but be consistent).

OrgProduct will have at least the Organization key and Product key as columns, and the combo of the two keys will be the key to OrgProduct.

If there are properties of the relationship, such as a date when the right of an Organization to sell a Product expires, these would also be candidates for non-key columns in this table.